Unable to update forge on windows
I am trying to run foundryup on windows to update foundry.

Tried with git bash, it gives me this error :
foundryup: installing foundry (version nightly, tag nightly)
foundryup: downloading latest forge, cast, anvil, and chisel
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
More details here: https://curl.se/docs/sslcerts.html
curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
foundryup: command failed: download https://github.com/foundry-rs/foundry/releases/download/nightly/foundry_nightly_win32_amd64.zip /tmp/tmp.yg70ODsk88/foundry.zip

then tried with WSL, now the problem is the forge is updated but only on WSL not on command prompt, means when I use forge --version on wsl it shows the latest version and when I do the same on windows cmd prompt it shows the old version. How can I fix this??


Here is an screenshot

